# Opensource Speech Recognition Library that is secure and trained on large data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, speech-to-text

For all those who are working on developing a chatbot/assistant and care about the privacy of users consuming the speech recognition library, can you suggest an open souce library which is trained on a large data. Big concern is the privacy that's why not going for Google Diagflow or IBM Watson or Amazon Lexa or Wit.

Would appreciate a lot if someone can suggest a good library.

Comment: Have you done some basic searching and found anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend having a look at [DeepSpeech](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You can find a maintained implementation of the project in [here](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech).

You may clone it, and train a model in order to have your very own model for speech recognition.

Comment: Thanks @Syed Ali Hamza. I"ll definitely have a look.